# Pythonでフォルダ内の複数のtxtファイルを一度に読み込み、dataFrameに格納したい

Tags: python

Jupyterで下記にある複数のtxtファイルを一度に読み込むにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。
やりたい事はPC内のfileというディレクトリに格納された22のファイルを読み込んで、それぞれを名前の異なるdataFrameに格納したいです。

皆様でしたらどうされるでしょうか。
大変恐縮ですが、ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

■txtファイル
1_1_0.txt
1_2_0.txt
1_3_0.txt
2_1_0.txt
2_2_0.txt
2_3_0.txt
2_4_0.txt
2_5_0.txt
2_6_0.txt
2_7_0.txt
2_8_0.txt
3_1_0.txt
3_2_0.txt
3_3_0.txt
3_4_0.txt
3_5_0.txt
3_6_0.txt
3_7_0.txt
3_8_0.txt
4_6_0.txt
4_7_0.txt
4_8_0.txt

Comment: 「ファイルを開いて、dataframeにデータを入れる」を２２回繰り返してください。
ほとんどの計算機やプログラミング言語は、同時に複数の作業ができるようになっていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の様にして、`pandas.DataFrame` オブジェクトを辞書(`dict`)に格納する方法も考えられます。
この場合、`df['1_1_0']` や `df['1_2_0']` などとしてアクセスする事が可能です。

```py
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

df = {}
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join("./", "file", "*.txt")):
  name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]
  df[name] = pd.read_csv(f)

name = sorted(df.keys())
for i in (0, -1):
  print(f"name = {name[i]}\n{df[name[i]]}")

# =>
name = 1_1_0
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
name = 4_8_0
   a  b  c
0  4  8  0
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec`を使用するのはでどうですかね。

```py
file_names = ['1_1_0', '1_2_0', '1_3_0', '2_1_0', '2_2_0', '2_3_0', '2_4_0', '2_5_0', '2_6_0', '2_7_0', '2_8_0', '3_1_0', '3_2_0', '3_3_0', '3_4_0', '3_5_0', '3_6_0', '3_7_0', '3_8_0', '4_6_0', '4_7_0', '4_8_0']
for file_name in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv('file/' + file_name + '.txt')
    exec('df_{} = df'.format(file_name))
del df
```

※ファイル数があまりにも多い場合は、このような少しトリッキーな方法でもいいと思いますが、1ファイルずつ読み込んだ方が可読性は高いかもしれません。

Comment: Kohei TAMURAさん　連絡ありがとうございます。
色々とすいません、別アカウントになっていた件など対応させて頂きました。

Comment: 先にコメントもらった内容を参考にコーディングした結果、上手く動作いたしました。大変ありがとうございました。