# Python（for文）でのグラフ作成について

Tags: python, python3

下記のリンク先にあるように複数のdataFrame（22個）を作成したのち、グラフを書かせる処理をしたいです。

[Pythonでフォルダ内の複数のtxtファイルを一度に読み込み、dataFrameに格納したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70395/python%e3%81%a7%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e5%86%85%e3%81%ae%e8%a4%87%e6%95%b0%e3%81%aetxt%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e4%b8%80%e5%ba%a6%e3%81%ab%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf-dataframe%e3%81%ab%e6%a0%bc%e7%b4%8d%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

グラフは下記の図の中に作成したいと思っていて、for文などでdataFrameを連続して読み込んで、処理を行えればと思っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その際にデータの無いdataFrameがあった場合に、データがないdataFrameはグラフを書かせないようにスキップして（エラーが出ないようにして）、for文などの連続した処理でグラフを書かせるには皆様でしたらどのように対応されますでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるでしょう。[matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), [Python で一枚のプロットに複数グラフを描く方法](https://stats.biopapyrus.jp/python/subplot.html), [Matplotlibの使い方④（plt.subplots、plt.title、plt.legend）｜Pythonによる可視化入門 #4](https://lib-arts.hatenablog.com/entry/Python_visualize4)

Answer (score 1):

以下は [matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) と [matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html?highlight=tight_layout#matplotlib-pyplot-tight-layout) を使う場合です。データフレームは乱数で適当に作成しています。

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w, h = 5, 5
fig = plt.figure()
for n in range(1, w*h+1):
  df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.linspace(0, 1.0, 11), 'y': np.random.rand(11),
  })
  ax = fig.add_subplot(w, h, n)
  ax.plot(df['x'], df['y'])
  ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 1.0, 2))
  ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1.0, 2))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example]